# Manually catch HTTPError/Exceptions in socket programming in Python

Tags: python, sockets, exception

I'm sending raw HTTP headers to a website, and I want to detect errors such as `400 Bad Request` or `404 Not Found` manually without using `urllib` or `Requests` package. I'm  sending a `HEAD` request like this:

```
head_request = "HEAD " + url_path + " HTTP/1.1\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n" % (host)
socket_id = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_id.connect((host, 80))
socket_id.send(head_request)
recv_head = socket_id.recv(1024)
```

How should I manually catch Exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to manually search for the HTTP response using a regular expression.

Another way is to port what you need from the http_parser.c module from the http-parser project.
It can be downloaded from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/http-parser/

You can parse the HTTP response using http-parser which works on the socket level.

Here is the description:

http-parser provide you parser.HttpParser low-level parser in C that you can access in your python program and http.HttpStream providing higher-level access to a readable,sequential io.RawIOBase object.

Here is how you can parse the HTTP response using sockets in Python in the manner according to the example you gave:

https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser/tree/master/http_parser

```
def main():

    p = HttpParser()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    body = []
    try:
        s.connect(('gunicorn.org', 80))
        s.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: gunicorn.org\r\n\r\n")

        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break

            recved = len(data)
            nparsed = p.execute(data, recved)
            assert nparsed == recved

           if p.is_headers_complete():
                print p.get_headers()

           if p.is_partial_body():
                body.append(p.recv_body())

           if p.is_message_complete():
               break

          print "".join(body)

    finally:
        s.close()
```

Comment: This does not answer my question, I'm looking for a manual way to handle some specific errors like 400, 404, etc., not using any external library as I explicitly mentioned in my question.

Comment: I fixed my answer to directly address your question of finding a manual means of detecting HTTP errors.  I hoped it helped you out.